# wget works from one ubuntu server but not another

Tags: ubuntu, wget, http-status-code-403

The command I am using: wget www.fivestarmazda.com/index.htm
Works on a digital ocean hosted ubuntu 14.10 machine
Works in chrome browser
Does NOT work in a rackspace hosted ubuntu 13.10 environment.
There, I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error.  Do you guys have any ideas why?  From all environments, I am able to wget http://www.google.com

Complete debug message from wget:

```
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.14 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2015-03-11 10:14:36--  http://www.fivestarmazda.com/index.htm
Resolving www.fivestarmazda.com (www.fivestarmazda.com)... 23.64.122.224
Caching www.fivestarmazda.com => 23.64.122.224
Connecting to www.fivestarmazda.com (www.fivestarmazda.com)|23.64.122.224|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000001eea330 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: www.fivestarmazda.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 964
X-DDC-Arch-Trace: ,HttpResponse
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 14:14:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

---response end---
403 Forbidden
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
URI content encoding = ‘utf-8’
Skipping 964 bytes of body: [<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} Skipping 452 bytes of body: [P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Access to the specified resource () has been forbidden.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.20</h3></body></html>] done.
2015-03-11 10:14:36 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Comment: This question is better asked in http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/  
stackoverflow is for programming questions only

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have now asked this same question on askubuntu.com here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/595548/wget-works-one-server-for-a-url-but-gets-403-forbidden-on-another

Comment: This is a bug in wget, try using curl.

Comment: I get the same 403 forbidden using curl.  I contacted rackspace, they suggested i set up another server in another datacenter.  I did that and wget works there just fine for all above examples.  The only difference I can see is that this new server is hosted in virginia while the other one is hosted in chicago.  there were a couple other servers hosted in chicago that rackspace tried from and could not get wget to work for www.fivestarmazda.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The reason was that on one account the environment variable 'http_proxy' was set. Since wget had no info about how to get through the proxy the access failed.